# Postgres: remember current ordering of entities, which is produced by doing SELECT without ORDER BY

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

It is known, that Postgres doesn't guarantee any particular order for a query without ORDER BY. But in most cases it will be the same order in which entities were written into DB.

It so happened, that in the project I'm now taking care of there is a lot of data (`Job` entities) written without any field denoting the their correct order. `Job`s are related to `Person`s and there is a need to understand which `Job` was the first created for a particular `Person` and which was the second.

So, I decided to add an `order` or just `created_at` field to `Job` and `ORDER BY` this field. I can write simple script to fill `created_at` or `order`. So far so good. But I am curious, is there a way to fill this `order` field automatically by issuing one `UPDATE` query?

Comment: "But in most cases it will be the same order in which entities were written into DB", until you start updating. You might want to look at the `ctid` column, see here [System columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-system-columns.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yeah. Do you mean, that `ORDER BY ctid` is the order in which rows are returned when no `ORDER BY` is supplied into the query?

Comment: Yes, for those times I have checked it. You should confirm it on your data set.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: isn't that only true if no parallel plan and no synchronized seq scan is involved?  If joins are involved then a hash join or a merge join could also result in a different order (other than by `ctid`) .

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Yes, I should have been more clear, I was talking about a simple single table query. That was why I pointed out `ctid` as way to force the 'order' on demand.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Guess, yours should be an accepted answer for my question

Comment: It was more a suggestion then a answer.